# hide backbutton embedded UINavigationController swift3

Tags: swift, back-button, navigationbar

I am using embedded navigationController with `Xcode8` and `Swift3`, i could have done some changes like transparent background etc but can not hide `backbutton` or change its title

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

How can i make the backbutton custom in navigation bar?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write this code under `viewWillAppear`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
}
```

If you want to add an image you can do:

```
let leftButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: buttonImage, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action:#selector(ViewController.leftButtonPress(sender:)))
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
```

Comment: thanks @Alessandro, it works but how can i change title or add a custom image?

Comment: I've update my answer, in other words you can customize it with UIBarButtonItem

Comment: thanks, i was trying to set `backButtonItem` which was wrong

Answer (score 0):

Design a custom `UIButton` and replace the default `NavigationBar` `BackBarButtonItem` with it.

```
func customBackButton() {
    let leftButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
    leftButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 36, 36)
    leftButton.clipsToBounds = true
    leftButton.setTitle("yourTitle", forState: .Normal) //set back button title
    leftButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "yourBackButton.png"), forState: .Normal) // add custom image
    leftButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onBackButton_Clicked(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    let leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem()
    leftBarButton.customView = leftButton
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton
}

func onBackButton_Clicked(sender: UIButton)
{
    if(webview.canGoBack) {
        webview.goBack()
    }
    else {
        self.navigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: first this is not working and it is not a swift3 syntax

Comment: Its Swift2.3. You may convert the logic to suit the specific syntax